# What does 'Output load (pull up or pull down' mean on a datasheet for a pressure transducer?

Tags: circuit-design, transducer

I am setting up a sensor network to monitor a few things including pressure. I am going through the following datasheet, [honeywell sensor](https://prod-edam.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell-edam/sps/siot/en-us/products/sensors/pressure-sensors/industrial-pressure-sensors/mip-series/documents/sps-siot-mip-series-high-pressure-datasheet-32354483-en.pdf), and it has a field called 'Output load (pull up or pull down)' with a value of >= 2kOhm.

Am I supposed to interpret that as to having to connect pull up or pull down resistor of 2 kOhm. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question it is just because it is an Analog output sensor, and I currently have one of them working without the resistor and it is working well.

Comment: It likely just means that their output cannot properly drive an input that "looks like" a resistance to ground (or positive rail) that is less than 2 k. This is just a current-compliance issue. Their output driver is "weak" and cannot handle a heavy load while also maintaining their precision specs. But I'd need to read the datasheet to offer better. Don't have the time right now.

Comment: Without a load resistor is the same as an infinitely large load resistor which is greater than 2 kOhm. But the  resistance of the used analog input connected to the sensor is smaller than infinity anyway. Of course you should not use a 50 Ohm terminated input.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet says the load must be 2k or larger. It means it can drive any load as long as it is 2k or larger and can't drive loads below 2k.

Having no load resistance at all is larger than 2k so that is perfectly fine within specs.